# how to search for two things and combine results ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a search form that has two text fields: Location and keyword.
The location goes through all entered listings and looks for the location tag, whereas the keyword looks at the description and title of the listing.

When a location and keyword is entered, listings that match both the location and keyword should show.
So if I enter San Francisco and Retail, only listings located in SF and with the description or title Retail should pop up.

I can't seem to get these two searches to combine.

Here is what I have
listing.rb

```
   class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category 
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :location, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true

    has_attached_file :resume

def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    self.where("title like ? or location like ? or description like ?", query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end

def self.locsearch(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    self.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)", query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end

end
```

Static_pages_controller.rb

```
  def home
    @listings = Listing.all
    @listings = @listings.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

home.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag findjobs_path, :controller => 'listings', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :location, "location"  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :keyword, "keyword"  %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
</div>
<% end %
```

listings_controller

```
    def index
  @listings = Listing.all 
  @listing = Listing.where(id: params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
#this is the simple search
  @listings = @listings.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
  @listings = @listings.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
#this is the complicated search from the homepage 
  @listings = @listings.locsearch(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
  @categories = Category.all

end

def search
  @listings = Listing.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)",params[:location], params[:keyword], params[:keyword])
end
end
```

---

When I add the suggested changes, deploy on heroku, do the search and run heroku logs I get the following

```
←[36m2014-09-19T23:12:02.140006+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"??
?", "location"=>"chicago", "keyword"=>"retail", "commit"=>"search"}
←[36m2014-09-19T23:12:02.170814+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (3.6ms)
←[36m2014-09-19T23:12:02.139998+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by ListingsCont
roller#index as HTML
←[36m2014-09-19T23:12:02.166290+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered listings/index.
html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms)
←[33m2014-09-19T23:12:02.677911+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h="/favicon.ico" host=nightjobs.herokuapp.com request_id=e3a13b6b-faf4-48c6-aad1
-7e0f88ce0a57 fwd="67.188.167.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304
bytes=133
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one query by the following:

```
self.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)", query, query, query)
```

Query form:

```
<%= form_tag findjobs_path, :controller => 'listings', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :location, "location"  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :keyword, "keyword"  %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
</div>
```

Static_pages_controller.rb

```
def search
  @listings = Listing.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)",params[:location], params[:keyword], params[:keyword])
end
```

Comment: okay, how would I add this to my view so that the location is just looking for the location and the keyword for title and description?

Comment: Can anyone help? How would I need to change the view in order to have one search for the location and the other for title and then get a combined result?

Comment: okay now it doesn't filter at all. I get all listings as a result.
For the search method, do I pass the parameters keyword and location?
Additionally, keyword is not a column in my listings table. Is that a factor?

Comment: My bad. I missed a parameter in my answer. I just updated, please check it again. `keyword` here is a parameter name. It doesn't matter here.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change. Also, is <%= form_tag findjobs_path, :controller => 'listings', or does is need to be :controller => 'static_pages'?

Comment: Note: Whenever I replace the parameter :search for for the text_field_tag to :location and :keyword, it does not filter at all. If I leave it as :search, it shows me the right title and description, however with the wrong location combination

Comment: I think it should be :controller => 'static_pages' here. We are adding the `search` action to this controller.

Comment: Could you show me the log after sending query request ?

Comment: Are you referring to the log in which I call my server? (rails s)

Comment: I deployed the website with heroku, did the search and run heroku logs. I added what I see above.

Comment: It seems that the listing_controller is processing the query request. So you could just change the action in listing_controller.

Comment: I added the function to the listings_controller and changes the query on the home.html.
There is still no change. 
I updated what I have now above.
Could you check if everything seems to be at the right place?
Also I have a another simple search function in the same listings_controller. Could this interfere with each other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61589/discussion-between-feng-chen-and-rika).

Comment: I just created a sample on Github, please check it out: https://github.com/santochan/query_sample